# Twitter Bootstrap 3 scrollspy won't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy

I just can't get scrollspy from bootstrap 3 to work.
I've already tried everything i've read from inumerous forums, including stackoverflow's answers, but with no success.

So if anyone could look at this code and help that would be great.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/ico/favicon.png">

        <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <style type="text/css">
          body {
            text-align: center;
          }

          #one, #two, #three, #four {
            height: 800px;
          }

        </style>

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="../../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
          <script src="../../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
      </head>

      <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#side-nav" data-offset="0">

    <nav id="side-nav">
        <ul class="nav nav-list affix">
          <li><a href="#one">one</a></li>
          <li><a href="#two">two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#three">three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#four">four</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

      <section id="one">one section</section>
      <section id="two">two section</section>
      <section id="three">three section</section>
      <section id="four">four section</section>


      </body>



        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <script src="../../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


      </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks in advance!!
Cheers!

EDIT:
you can check it NOT working in the following URL:
http://zumuha.site40.net/bootstrap/examples/starter-template/

Cheers!

Comment: What is happening? How does it look?

Comment: The anchor links work on click but when i scroll, it doesn't update in the #side-nav like it should.

Comment: DO you see any errors in console. Are you sure you have the required styles and everything. Check this it works here.. http://jsbin.com/azejOqA/1/ and http://jsbin.com/azejOqA/1/edit

Comment: No errors in console.
Must be the styling then.

But i've already installed Bootstrap several times from scratch and didn't messed with the styles.

It should work on-the-fly...
I don't understand this...

I've just uploaded an example in a free web server... 
The problem still exists...

Comment: You used bootstrap 2.3.2 right?
I'm using Bootstrap 3.0.0...

Comment: Just upgrade your styles and make sure you have style rules for nav-list in your bootstrap css and all should work well.

Comment: @PSL I changed your code to bootstrap 3.0.0 an it didn't work. New css `http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css` and remove the second `link`

Comment: @DanielCheung That is what i said this css doesn't have `nav-list` rules in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is very clear if you open Inspect Element and look at the `#side-nav`'s `li`s. You need to style the style on the `.active` class they provide you.

@PSL said you missed something and said they provide a styled `.active` class. But based on your website, I don't see the style in Inspect Element. (The official zipped website also dosen't have the `.active` style in bootstrap.css, they added in a custom bs-doc.css which included the style)

The correct troubleshooting would be styling the css yourself:

Which is `#side-nav > .nav > .active` in css. Try to put a `font-weight: bold;` in it.

I had this same problem before, so I would recommend you to **download the official zipped bootstrap website** and change upon them. A tip here: **Bootstrap change a lot even though the version doesn't change**, so you can also download the newest css and try.

Comment: Incorrect OP's issue is only with the css. bootstrap js alread adds active class based on the scroll. He needs to use css which has the styles for that.

Comment: Perfect...
Thanks to PSL for the help.

Comment: He means font-weight ;)

Comment: @VajkHermecz Thanks, I just realize it, why would I type `text-weight`?